# ngx chart scale/range value in units

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

As per the attached snapshot scale/range of the heatmap is displaying the data values. Need to display value in units i.e like 2140000 to be displayed as 2 GB.

Code Sample --
[image: Pic]
export class App {

```
//single: any[];
multi: any[];

// Size to be displayed 
view: any[] = [1000, 400];

// options

showXAxis = true;
showYAxis = true;
gradient = false;
showLegend = true;
showXAxisLabel = true;
xAxisLabel = 'Hour';
showYAxisLabel = true;
yAxisLabel = 'Days';
```

}

Refer [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2rtX5cueg2hlzmztUbkH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think.

You can simply add suffix with this class:

```
::ng-deep .scale-legend-label span:after {
  content: " GB";
}
```

But to display values in other units, you should provide already calculated ones to the heatmap:

Before you pass data to [results], execute a method which will convert the data to GB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to format each data to GB unit. Then your legend will follow to this unit too.

Actually, there's some ways to customize your legend like this [advanced-legend](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/common/legend/advanced-legend.component.ts) example on the official repo or [this one](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/common/legend/legend.component.ts).

There's also [an opened issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/993) about that on the official repo again.

So for the moment, I think you should format the chart's data to GB unit to make the legend follow. Or customize the legend as shown above, or wait an official feature.